# SCRIPT70: Permission denied File: saw.dll, Line: 1, Column: 802 error

Tags: obiee

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU2Mg.jpg)

I have created a `obiee` landing page using HTML and Javascript where I have created a simple side navigation bar with link to other `obiee` dashboards, but while I am clicking the link `obiee` report is opening in the frame present in html code but the `obiee` reports prompts is not working sometime, but the same report is working properly in CHROME browser.

I have done `inspect element --> console` in web-browser(IE) there I have found the below error while clicking the prompts

> SCRIPT70: Permission denied File: saw.dll, Line: 1, Column: 802 and
>   saw.ajax.Connection._handleNotification: Permission denied

Strange thing is when first time the page is loading then the prompt ois working fine

** NB Same is working properly in CHROME BROWSER

not able to understand what is the issue tried all the permission at report level

Comment: What exact version is that? Looks extremely old.

Comment: IE11.0.9600.1926

Comment: ...of OBIEE. Not just Internet Explorer.

Comment: obiee 11g 11.1.1.7.141014 . same page is working properly in Chrome

Comment: when page is loading that time it is working fine but when changing url using custom side navigation bar made using html  and want to see the page in iframe ... that time page is opening but when trying to click prompt is is giving the error

Comment: can anyone please help ..this has become a bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

1.) Stop using "custom side navigation bar". If you hack a prefabricated application with your own code, the error is on your side.

2.) Upgrade your OBIEE. It's very old and no longer supported.

3.) Using Internet Explorer is a bad choice to begin with and if you looked at the support sites you would see that most browser-related issues reported are all for Internet Explorer.

Comment: thanks for the solution ..seems like horse is free if i buy jockey .

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, but you also wounldn't go and write a custom engine management system for your car.